# How to disable scratch in scratch card view?

Tags: android

This is what I have done,

```
holder.scratchView.setRevealListener(new ScratchView.IRevealListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRevealed(ScratchView scratchView) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Reveled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onRevealPercentChangedListener(ScratchView scratchView, float percent) {
                if (percent >= 0.5) {
                    Log.e("Reveal Percentage", "onRevealPercentChangedListener: " + String.valueOf(percent));
                }
            }
        });
```

How to disable scratch in a scratch card view?

Comment: Please provide more information to the code other than "How to disable scratch". If it's a library please provide more description and check their official documentation. Maybe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) can help you get started!

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are using this library :- 
https://github.com/sharish/ScratchView

So, basically do,

```
holder.scratchView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // Do nothing
            return false;
        }
```

The downside is, you cannot enable it again